# Renaming x-b3-traceid header in spring cloud

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-sleuth

I'm trying to configure Spring sleuth 2.0.3.RELEASE to propagate trace ids through my service calls. By default it sends x-b3-traceid header in the request, but i'm unable to rename the header to say, x-request-id instead.
Is there any out-of-the-box method, or preferred method to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't rename it but add another one that will be propagated. You can read about this in brave docs https://github.com/apache/incubator-zipkin-brave/blob/master/brave/README.md#propagating-extra-fields

However in Sleuth you don't have to run those methods. It's enough for you to set a property

```
spring.sleuth.propagation-keys=yourHeaderName
```

You can read about it here https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Greenwich.SR1/single/spring-cloud.html#prefixed-fields

Comment: thanks, however a question here,  wouldn't adding a new field be like re-inventing the wheel again since i'll have to write the code to manage the value I send in the header. In my mind, the benefit of using sleuth was that it takes away the overhead of managing the tracking-ids.

Comment: It's much much easier to do it that way. Otherwise you'd have to implement more beans which makes little sense. With this you ensure that you have standard headers and you're custom one that also has trace id. It's a win win situation.

Comment: @MarcinGrzejszczak what are the repercussions of renaming it ? in my use case i just want to use correlationID as header value.

Comment: @MarcinGrzejszczak - reading release doc for 2.2.6.RELESE , still its telling use ExtraFieldPropagation but tis deprecated... is that support doc is wrong ?